# Mobile/IOS app in Flex Builder 3?

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

is it possible to publish a mobile (specifically IOS) app using Flex Builder 3, or is this only available on Flash Builder 4.5 and later?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile support is only available in Flash Builder 4.5 and later.  You can use the free command line tools to create mobile applications; but I strongly recommend that you upgrade your tooling because it will save you a lot of headaches.

Although it is possible, I am not sure I would recommend trying to publish a Flex 3 based app to iOS or any mobile platform.  Rewriting the app to use Spark components is going to give a much more optimized performance.